# Groovy cli script doesn't set classpath

Tags: visual-studio-code, groovy, command-line-interface, classpath

I get the following when executing my Groovy script:

```
satchwinston@MacBook-Air groovy-cli % ./encryptor.groovy -e hgjjgjgkgk
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/Users/satchwinston/Development/test/groovy-cli/encryptor.groovy: 11: unable to resolve class bnc.Encryption
 @ line 11, column 1.
   import bnc.Encryption
   ^

1 error
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
'''':
exec groovy -cp  "/Users/satchwinston/Development/test/picocli-groovy-4.7.5.jar:bnc.jar" "$0"
'''

import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path

import groovy.cli.picocli.CliBuilder

import bnc.Encryption

def encrypt(string) {
  (new Encryption()).encrypt(string)
}

def decrypt(string) {
  (new Encryption()).decrypt(string)
}

// Main
def cli = new CliBuilder(usage:'encryptor ([-e] | [-d]) ([-in filename] | <arg>) > <filename>', header:'Options')
cli.e('encrypt')
cli.d('decrypt')
cli.in('input filename')
def options = cli.parse(args)

if (args.length = 0 || (args.length != 2 && args.length != 3)) {
  println(cli.usage())
  System.exit(1) 
}

def e = options.e ?: false
def d = options.d ?: false
def in = options.in ?: ""
def str = in.length == 0 ? args[1] : ""

if (e && str.length() > 0)
  println(encrypt(str))
else if (e)
  println(encrypt(Files.readString(Path.of(in))))
else if (d && str.length > 0)
  println(decrypt(str))
else if (d)
  println(decrypt(Files.readString(Path.of(in))))
else {
  println(cli.usage())
  System.exit(1)
}

System.exit(0)
```

It looks like it can use the picocli jar but not my bnc.jar.

```
satchwinston@MacBook-Air test % jar -tf bnc.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
bnc/Encryption.class
satchwinston@MacBook-Air test %
```

I had this problem with Scala too. I had to resort to using a Scala directive:
//> using jars /Users/satchwinston/Development/test/bnc.jar

Using --classpath did not work.

Comment: Tried with the full path, and not just `bnc.jar` as in the question?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. the classpath specified is /Userst/satchwinston/test/Users/satchwinston/test/picocli-groovy-4.7.5.jar:bnc.jar

Comment: I've also tried: > groovy -cp  "/Users/satchwinston/test/picocli-groovy-4.7.5.jar:bnc.jar" encryptor.groovy

Comment: I don't understand why we can't use #!/usr/bin/env/ groovy -cp ... The env thing must not pass the -cp arg to groovy. I should be able to use #!/Users/satchwinston/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin/groovy -cp ... and it should work. Or put an alias to groovy in /usr/bin/.

Comment: Looks like it just can't find bnc.jar because you are executing it from a different directory.  Looks like you are runnning it from groovy-cli, but bnc.jar exists under test.  And the classpath just refers to bnc.jar.  I think if you specify the full path to bnc.jar in the classpath it should work.

Comment: -cp "/Users/satchwinston/Development/test/*" should frigging work but it doesn't.

Comment: I made a lib directory with just the two jar files but -cp "/Users/satchwinston/Development/test/lib/* doesn't work either. Crazy.